# The name PageFactory does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, page-factory

I am using a POM in C# with Xunit as a framework, and am getting error in pagefactory for the following code:

```
PageFactory.InitElements(driver, login);
```

> Error: "The name PageFactory does not exist in current context", what
>   is the solution for this?

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734097/the-name-pagefactory-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score 2):

The `PageFactory` class is now considered deprecated in the Selenium binaries; that could be the issue.  But, I would still try adding the following to your code to see if it will resolve.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;
```

Failing that, you could use `NuGet` to install [this package](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/DotNetSeleniumExtras) in your project.

Comment: I've installed the package dotnet selenium extras , it's working, however am not able to write anythings in the textbox using sendkeys, getting an error as Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object., would be great if anyone helps this.

Comment: You should create a new question for the issue you mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Search for DotNetSeleniumExtras in Nuget Packages manager and install all of them including waitHelpers